# Merge multiple table output but indicate which tables the records came from

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, join

I have an application with a function that uses a stored procedure (SQL Server 2008 R2) to pull in and arrange data from one table.  Now, I’ve been asked to make it pull from two tables, but it’s not just a straight join.  The tables have overlapping records (a common ID field between them), so my end result needs to have a field that indicates whether that row had a record from Table A only, from Table B only, or if it had records in both Tables A and B.

I am not a SQL guru (my queries are usually just selects with simple joins), so I’m having a hard time figuring this out.  My current thought is to create three temp tables (one for A-only records, one for B-only records, and one for A+B records) then union them together for the output, but I’m sure there’s a better, more elegant/proper way to do this.  Any thoughts on how this could be accomplished?

---

[image: table setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a full outer join between your tables and check against null values to figure out where the data comes from.

```
select isnull(A.ID, B.ID) as ID,
       isnull(A.Name, B.Name) as Name,
       case
         when A.ID is null then 'B'
         when B.ID is null then 'A'
         else 'A+B'
       end as Tables   
from TableA as A
  full outer join TableB as B
    on A.ID = B.ID
```